# Faking polyphony with single sound channel

Tags: audio, assembly, emulation

I am writing music for an emulated system ([Chip16](http://www.doc.ic.ac.uk/~tk2010/tutorials/chip16/beginner/spec.txt)), which can output ADSR formatted sound to a single channel.

Furthermore, it can only play one sound at any given time, cutting off a playing sound if necessary.

If I wanted a beat or bass playing "behind" the melody, how would I go about doing that?
Are there any tricks to simulate polyphony?

I am aware of how it was done on IBM PC speakers -- but that relied on the physical/mechanical nature of the device, which is not possible here.

For reference, the available sound instructions:

```
sng 0xAD, 0xVTSR       ; load Attack,Decay,Volume,Type,Sustain,Release params
snp rx, D              ; play sound, with frequency at [rx], for D milliseconds
snd0                   ; stop currently playing sound
```

Thanks!

Comment: So the `snp` instruction plays a single audio frequency, and only one `snp` instruction can be executing at once?

Comment: The sort of classic way of simulating polyphony is to alternate sounds rapidly, or arpeggiate.

Comment: @A.Webb How fast are we talking? Are there any examples of this behaviour?

Comment: You can find all sorts of examples if you search around for "arpeggiator". You can vary the speed as well as the time intervals spent on each sound to vary effects. Why not code up something in your environment and play around with it?

Comment: @A.Webb Thanks! I will come up with something.